# SAPUI5 : Is it possible to do a nested binding in a binding filter

Tags: xml, binding, nested, filtering, sapui5

I have a xml view with a `TabFilterBar` that includes two `IconTabFilter`.
The property `count` for the first `IconTabFilter` is bound like this :

```
count="{/TestDataSet(Systemid='XYZ', Version='1.0')/Value1}"
```

And for the second `IconTabFilter`:

```
count="{/TestDataSet(Systemid='XYZ', Version='1.0')/Value2}"
```

Inside the binding I do a filtering.
For now the filter values for `Systemid` and `Version` are just hard coded.

I want now to read the filter values out of a model.

For that I created a JSON Model `filterModel`. In this model I have a property for `Systemid` and one for `Version`. It holds the actual value for this property.

I am able to use and read the new model with it's properties in the XML view:

```
{filterModel>systemid}
{filterModel>version}
```

I tried know to include that in my binding of the `IconTabFilter`.
It looks like this:

```
<IconTabBar id="TabFilterBar">
  <items>
    <IconTabFilter id="TabFilterOne" icon="sap-icon://database" iconColor="Neutral" text="{i18n>TabFilterOne}" count="{/TestDataSet(Systemid='{filterModel>systemid}', Version='{filterModel>version}')/Value1}"/>
    <IconTabFilter id="TabFilterTwo" icon="sap-icon://check-availability" iconColor="Neutral" text="{i18n>TabFilterTwo}" count="{/TestDataSet(Systemid='{filterModel>systemid}', Version='{filterModel>version}')/Value2}"/>
  </items>
```

But this is not working.

How can I archieve to use a binding nested in a filter of a binding?

Comment: Binding will not work like that, try to use [Property Binding](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon10/1.17/en-US/91/f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm?no_cache=true). Get the `IconTabFilter` instance and bind the `count` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think it’s possible to actually nest the props. I would do it the following way:

```xml
<IconTabBar id="TabFilterBar" binding="{/TestDataSet(Systemid='XYZ', Version='1.0')}">
  <items>
    <IconTabFilter count="{Value1}" id="TabFilterOne" icon="sap-icon://database" iconColor="Neutral" text="{i18n>TabFilterOne}"/>
    <IconTabFilter count="{Value2}" id="TabFilterTwo" icon="sap-icon://check-availability" iconColor="Neutral" text="{i18n>TabFilterTwo}"/>
  </items>
</IconTabBar>
```

And update binding of the `IconTabBar` whenever your filter is changed from within the controller. Something like

```js
  this.getView().byId("TabFilterBar").bindObject("/TestDataSet(Systemid='ABC', Version='47.11')")
```

should do it

Comment: Hi iPirat, thank you for your reply ! :) Is there a way to use expression binding ("inline formatter") to realize the full logic in the xml view ?

Comment: @ChristianR you would need to pass both "full set" `TestDataSet` and the settings `filterModel>/` to your formatter and get the required objects/values there. that should work (technically) but this is far from the binding concept and you just move the logic to the formatter. I dont think it is somehow possible to do things like `{/TestDataSet(SystemId={{folterModel>system}}, ...}` if that is what you mean

Comment: @iPirit : Yes I thought of sth close to that - to avoid to write a formatter function and keep the binding logic inside the xml view: `count={/TestDataSet(SystemId='{= ${filterModel>systemid}}', Version='{={$filterModel>version}}')}` What do you mean with: "far away from the binding concept" ?